# How to add simple app launching animation when AppDelegate loading data from CSV?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-data

I made an app. At first install to phone, app creating CoreData from CSV file in AppDelegate. It takes around 10 seconds.

So i want to show user some loading animation(circle or progress bar or something else).

This is my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, where at first launching, app parsing CSV file(around 15000 entity objects) with function preloadDataFromCSVFile().

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let isPreloaded = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: isPreloadedKey)
    if !isPreloaded {
        preloadDataFromCSVFile()
        defaults.set(true, forKey: isPreloadedKey)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't do it in the AppDelegate. Do the loading in your first view controller where you can also display an animation. When the loading is complete segue to your current first view controller. Make sure you dispatch the load onto another queue so that it doesn't block the main queue otherwise your display won't update.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks, that is really what i misunderstand. Add you answer and i mark it as correct.